# terra shade function not stacking different angles and directions with my own data (as per example)

Tags: r, raster, terra, elevation

I have tried to replicate the las t section of the example from the `shade` function in `terra` with my own data to improve the hillshade with the use of several directions and angles, but the resulting object has no values. And therefore, no mean is produced with the `Reduce` function. The object  with the simple shade parameter (with one angle and direction, as per the example) works fine.

There is no error message whatsoever, just no values in the final output raster as show below. not sure if this is because of a size limitation of `terra` (maybe?).

My code:

```
library(terra)
elevation <- terra::rast(file.choose())

alt <- terra::disagg(elevation , 10, method="bilinear")

slope <- terra::terrain(alt, "slope", unit="radians")

aspect <- terra::terrain(alt, "aspect", unit="radians")

#basic hillshade
hill <- terra::shade(slope, aspect, 40, 270)

terra::plot(hill)
terra::plot(hill, col=grey(0:100/100), legend=FALSE, mar=c(2,2,1,4))


#get a better shade with different angles and directions

h <- terra::shade(slope, aspect, angle = c(45, 45, 45, 80), direction = c(225, 270, 315, 135))

h <- Reduce(mean, h)            
terra::plot(h)
```

Either before the `Reduce` or after, h has this output (and its seems to run in less than a second, which is not the case for run with only 1 angle and direction, hill):

```
h
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 18640, 15930, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 100, 100  (x, y)
extent      : -2791000, -1198000, 1522000, 3386000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

The elevation I am trying to use could be found here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12yezqqNutfD19eyxJmbL9WqvwTdcjT3e/view?usp=sharing

Any input would be appreciated!

Cheers and Thanks!!

EDIT: After Chris pointed out that it may be a memory issue of the function attempting to run and stack 4 shade at a time to improve the shading I attempted something that may be a "fix", or just shows that the function is breaking internally with large rasters when trying to produce several shades.

I just tried this:

```
h1 <- terra::shade(slope, aspect, angle = 45, direction = 225)
h2 <- terra::shade(slope, aspect, angle = 45, direction = 270)
h3 <- terra::shade(slope, aspect, angle = 45, direction = 315)
h4 <- terra::shade(slope, aspect, angle = 80, direction = 135)

stack1 <- c(h1, h2, h3, h4)



#check the stacked shades   
stack1

class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 18640, 15930, 4  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 100, 100  (x, y)
extent      : -2791000, -1198000, 1522000, 3386000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
sources     : spat_5bc87444484_23496.tif  
              spat_5bc8105f55ed_23496.tif  
              spat_5bc82d144698_23496.tif  
              spat_5bc819d7aac_23496.tif  
varnames    : elevation_cropped (1) 
              elevation_cropped (1) 
              elevation_cropped (1) 
              ...
names       :  hillshade,  hillshade,  hillshade, hillshade 
min values  : 0.04666001, 0.09771556, 0.04562845,  0.634741 
max values  : 0.99999017, 0.99748391, 0.99444449,  1.000000 


meanh <- terra::app(stack1, "mean")

par(mfrow= c(1,2))
terra::plot(hill, col=grey(0:100/100), legend=FALSE, mar=c(2,2,1,4))
terra::plot(meanh, col=grey(0:100/100), legend=FALSE, mar=c(2,2,1,4))
```

[image: comparison_of_shades]

The mean shade is produced, and its surely different than the original shade. Memory didn't explode. So this is maybe a bug or issue within the function.

Edit2: I compared this 1 by 1 approach, and the "group shading" from the example in the documentation, just to check if the raster results were the same, and there is a slight difference. The max and min value don't match. But they are visually similar. So there is something else the function is doing internally. I haven't been able to look at source code. Not sure I want to dig into that.

Example from the documentation
[image]

Original h object from the documentation example (grouped shading)

```
h
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 900, 950, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.0008333333, 0.0008333333  (x, y)
extent      : 5.741667, 6.533333, 49.44167, 50.19167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source(s)   : memory
varname     : elev 
name        : hs_45_225 
min value   : 0.5087930 
max value   : 0.8495533
```

My object ("individual shading and mean after")

```
meanh
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 900, 950, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.0008333333, 0.0008333333  (x, y)
extent      : 5.741667, 6.533333, 49.44167, 50.19167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source(s)   : memory
name        :      mean 
min value   : 0.6748505 
max value   : 0.8538219
```

Comment: For your plots, one wants to be hill, col = grey( the other alt with an alpha =  say 0.25, as per ?terra::shade examples.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, actually in this example, I didn't need to plot with add=TRUE as I am just trying to show my problem in producing the h object only, with multiple angles and directions. And I didn't want to plot the overlay yet (because I dont get h to come out right) I have edited the description accordingly.

Comment: I think you want to run your h again, then rename to say h2 for the Reduce as you h should have 4 layers, and with Reduce we're back to 1 layer. Useful to employ this expanded naming till you're comfortable with/about expected outputs. And as Reduce is said to offer 'better' shade, combining the angles and directions of `h`, the `mean` is across all 4 layers resulting in `h2` of 1 layer.

Comment: Thanks for the input! The issue is that the first `h` has no layers at all (not even 1, so surely not 4 as its supposed to). It shows like the example I posted above, with dimensions, resolution, extent, etc. but no values at all, and the shade function to produce it runs in a fraction of a second, seemingly not doing anything, but no error message either.

Comment: I think we take advantage of `terra` memory handling by actively naming layers `filename =` that will both write files in current directory and only use values as needed, then run the two approaches (one at a time then stack) and angle = c(, and try filename = c(, under debugonce(shade) and see how things go. And I'm going to do this in new directory.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I tried `h <- terra::shade(slope, aspect, angle = c(45, 45, 45, 80), direction = c(225, 270, 315, 135), filename = "raster.stack.tif")` and I got `Error: [shade] there are no cell values`. Without `filename =` the same line produces no error whatsoever, but  but an object SpatRaster with no layers at all.

Comment: [multidirectional shade added](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/948) with discussion of 'hard to see effect in low resolution', hence disagg 10 on `elev`, unclear whether tested on larger rasters further subjected to disagg. And as to [disagg and memory]( https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/1334) which may or may not be in play but have to check my ?terraOptions `wopt`(s). Note below get values from shade on alt without disagg.

Comment: Thanks again! Not sure now if I should mark my question as answered? Or solved? of expand on the github issues you linked above. I am new to stackoverflow interactions!

Comment: We've kicked it around, without resolution, and I'd say that this might rise to a new issue, as one would expect that whether done in memory or not, the results (4 layers with values) would be the same, and yet they're not. Robert Hijmans is frequent visitor here, but do the new issue with a link to this question. As this is without resolution don't accept my answer. I don't think we've done any missteps in our exploration and there may indeed need to be an adjustment to the `terra`code. Thanks for the interesting question.

Comment: Great, I have opened the issue here, with a different map (to avoid the need of my link, as per SO suggestions) but it produces the same issue in my computer, no layers and no error message.
https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/1452

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your data I get the following, one just using the resolution of the cropped raster, the next disagg-d:

```
library(terra)
terra 1.7.73

alt = rast('~/Downloads/elevation_cropped.tif')
alt = rast('~/Downloads/elevation_cropped.tif')
alt_slope = terrain(alt, 'slope', unit='radians', filename = 'alt_slope.tif')
alt_aspect = terrain(alt, 'aspect', unit='radians', filename = 'alt_aspect.tif')
alt_shade = shade(alt_slope, alt_aspect, angle = c(45,45,45,80), direction = c(225,270,315,135), filename = 'alt_shade.tif')
alt_shade
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 1864, 1593, 4  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
extent      : -2791000, -1198000, 1522000, 3386000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source      : alt_shade.tif 
varname     : elevation_cropped 
names       : hs_45_225, hs_45_270, hs_45_315, hs_80_135 
min values  : 0.1426585, 0.1348058, 0.1915113, 0.6898556 
max values  : 0.9902307, 0.9877117, 0.9785777, 0.9999999
```

`disagg`

```
alt2 = disagg(alt, 10, method = 'bilinear')
alt2_slope = terrain(alt2, 'slope', unit='radians')
alt2_aspect = terrain(alt2, 'aspect', unit='radians')


hill2 = terra::shade(alt2_slope, alt2_aspect, angle = c(45,45,45,80), direction = c(225,270,315,135))

hill2                                   
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 18640, 15930, 4  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 100, 100  (x, y)
extent      : -2791000, -1198000, 1522000, 3386000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
sources     : spat__2.tif  
              memory  
              memory  
              memory  
varnames    : elevation_cropped 
              elevation_cropped 
              elevation_cropped 
              ...
names       :  hs_45_225, hs_45_270, hs_45_315, hs_80_135 
min values  : 0.04666001,        ? ,        ? ,        ?  
max values  : 0.99999017,        ? ,        ? ,        ?
```

So, ? marks or no layers at all, or memory not mapped crash. [Multidirectional shade](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/948) points out that it provides 'better' results for low resolution rasters, and the example file used was

```
 f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
     r <- rast(f)
dim(r)
[1] 90 95  1
```

and this is very low resolution. Unfortunately, for the unwary (which would be both of us), the `disagg` process made it into the ?shade example as a 'better' final product, and we didn't pause to think that perhaps 'elevation_cropped' was already at a good resolution. The ensuing results of further `disagg` were certainly unexpected... I still think this is worthy of mention at [terra issues](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues) at least as to help.

As it turns out, it can be done. Using [wopt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77552234/controlling-chunk-size-in-terra) and insights from [mem_info, memmax](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/1334) that highlights the memory required but writes to disk, so giving more memory 'elbow room' via `wopts` list allows processing to go

```
alt2_shade = shade(alt2_slope, alt2_aspect, angle = c(45,45,45,80), direction = c(225,270,315,135), filename = 'alt2_shade2.tif', overwrite = TRUE, wopt = list(memmax = 0.6, verbose = TRUE))
filename      : /tmp/Rtmpt0OHpP/spat__2.tif
compute stats : 1, GDAL: 0, minmax: 0, approx: 1
driver        : GTiff
disk available: 782.5 GB
disk needed   : 1.1 GB
memory avail. : 0.6 GB
memory allow. : 0.36 GB
memory needed : 8.849 GB  (4 copies)
in memory     : false
block size    : 454 rows
n blocks      : 42
pb            : 3

filename      : /tmp/Rtmpt0OHpP/spat__2.tif
compute stats : 1, GDAL: 0, minmax: 0, approx: 1
driver        : GTiff
disk available: 782.5 GB
disk needed   : 1.1 GB
memory avail. : 0.6 GB
memory allow. : 0.36 GB
memory needed : 8.849 GB  (4 copies)
in memory     : false
block size    : 454 rows
n blocks      : 42
pb            : 3
```

progress bar

```
filename      : /tmp/Rtmpt0OHpP/spat__2.tif
compute stats : 1, GDAL: 0, minmax: 0, approx: 1
driver        : GTiff
disk available: 782.5 GB
disk needed   : 1.1 GB
memory avail. : 0.6 GB
memory allow. : 0.36 GB
memory needed : 8.849 GB  (4 copies)
in memory     : false
block size    : 454 rows
n blocks      : 42
pb            : 3

filename      : /tmp/Rtmpt0OHpP/spat__2.tif
compute stats : 1, GDAL: 0, minmax: 0, approx: 1
driver        : GTiff
disk available: 782.5 GB
disk needed   : 1.1 GB
memory avail. : 0.6 GB
memory allow. : 0.36 GB
memory needed : 8.849 GB  (4 copies)
in memory     : false
block size    : 454 rows
n blocks      : 42
pb            : 3
```

progress bar

```
filename      : alt2_shade2.tif           
compute stats : 1, GDAL: 0, minmax: 0, approx: 1
driver        : GTiff
disk needed   : 4.4 GB
memory avail. : 0.6 GB
memory allow. : 0.36 GB
memory needed : 17.699 GB  (2 copies)
in memory     : false
block size    : 227 rows
n blocks      : 83
pb            : 3

alt2_shade                              
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 18640, 15930, 4  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 100, 100  (x, y)
extent      : -2791000, -1198000, 1522000, 3386000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source      : alt2_shade2.tif 
varname     : elevation_cropped 
names       : hs_45_225, hs_45_270, hs_45_315, hs_80_135 
min values  :  0.634741,  0.634741,  0.634741,  0.634741 
max values  :  1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000
```

But can it usefully be plotted? First Reduce(

```
alt2_shade_reduce = Reduce(mean, alt2_shade)
alt2_shade_reduce
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 18640, 15930, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 100, 100  (x, y)
extent      : -2791000, -1198000, 1522000, 3386000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source      : alt2_shade2.tif 
varname     : elevation_cropped 
name        : hs_45_225 
min value   :  0.634741 
max value   :  1.000000 
writeRaster(alt2_shade_reduce, 'alt2_shade_reduce_.tif')
```

Plot looks fine, and better.

```
ls -lah stackoverflow_shade
-rw-rw-r--  1 chris chris 899M Mar 10 16:54 alt2.tif
-rw-rw-r--  1 chris chris 942M Mar 11 10:04 alt2_slope.tif
-rw-rw-r--  1 chris chris 931M Mar 11 10:05 alt2_aspect.tif
-rw-rw-r--  1 chris chris 766M Mar 11 11:51 alt2_shade_reduce_.tif
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! Surprisingly I just tried it now, and for the first time, I am getting the ? signs in the 2nd to 4th layers, as well. So now I got your voodoo. So maybe it is a memory thing. Which is surprising, because, I have already stacked several layers of topography rasters, which takes long, but its doesn't collapse like this. I guess the "shade" interal processing would make the memory issue. Not sure if this is something to be raised as an issue in the package's github page? Any suggestion.

Comment: Thinking about the memory issue by running the 4 shades internally, I tried another approach, by running 4 independent shades, stacking, and averaging the stack after and I think it worked. I just edited my initial question! And wonder if this is a bug that should be reported in terra's github?

Comment: I'll try your 1 by 1 approach in just a little bit.

Comment: Great! Thanks! I compared my new approach (1 by 1 and then mean) to the "grouped shading" approach of the example file in the terra documentation. Just checked if the final raster values checked. There is a slight difference, and will update in my initial question.

Comment: Thanks for the update Chris! I see now that `dissag` was the culprit (and us not really skipping it, I thought about it, but got hooked with the apparent issue). I tried once without `filename= test1.png` but with the `wopt` and it produced no layers. But when adding the `filename` the layers are produced.  I guess I will edit the github issue as the function should still give at least a warning message or error if its maxing out the memory, like in other instance of terra functions. Thanks again for troubleshooting this with me! Will check this question as answered now!

Comment: It will be useful for both of us to wrap our heads around available tests for 'memory' issues. Mine were a matter of (default?) settings, that are adjustable via `wopt`. I did have trouble getting giscoR working in your github example that I'll look at again. There is an upper (default) bound on memory used by R as process, a kind of play nice on the system, at about 2GB (I think) that I haven't tinkered with since building a new box but will also explore.

Comment: Hi Chris! giscoR doesn't give me any trouble. The next function does take long with a `z=10` which increases the resolution of the elevation raster, and I want to make the point of having a high res raster makes the `shade` function to crash. After getting the elevation raster at 10 resolution, and with the dissag the whole thing does take a long long time. But it should work. But if you are having issues with giscoR, not sure why, you can't eve get to the elevation high res issues.